# how to debug a large view which return error after select , how to see where the problem come from

Tags: sql-server

I have a  view, after I execute the query it give me an error like this

[image]

Anyone please help, how can I debug to solve this problem.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT LEAD_CO_MNE, ACCOUNT_NO, CLOSURE_TYPE, DATE_TIME, Rank() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE_TIME]) AS rank_
FROM   [InsightSource].BS.AA_ACCOUNT_CLOSURE_DETAILS) aat
WHERE aat.rank_ = 1), Curr AS
    (SELECT CurrencyCodeFrom, MidRevalRate
    FROM    [dbo].[v_SourceCurrencyBS]
    WHERE SourceCurrencyID LIKE concat('BS:', 'BNK', ':', '%', 'KHR', ':1')), LoanSettlementAccount AS
    (SELECT a.[ID_COMP_1] AS [@ID], [Sequence], b.[PAYIN_ACCOUNT] AS LoanSettlementAccount, row_number() OVER (partition BY a.[ID_COMP_1]
    ORDER BY [Sequence] ASC) AS RowNum
FROM   [InsightSource].[BS].[AA_ARR_SETTLEMENT] a LEFT OUTER JOIN
             [InsightSource].[BS].[AA_ARR_SETTLEMENT_PAYIN_ACCOUNT] b ON a.[@ID] = b.[@ID])
    SELECT DISTINCT 
                [Date].BusinessDate AS [BusinessDate], aa.LEAD_CO_MNE AS LeadCompany, 'BS' AS SourceSystem, concat('BS:', com.FINANCIAL_MNE, ':', cast(aa.[LINKED_APPL_ID] AS nvarchar(50))) AS [SourceAccountId], concat('BS:', CO_CHK.COMPANY_MNE, ':', 
                CAST(isnull(A.[CO_CODE], aa.[CO_CODE]) AS nvarchar(50))) AS [SourceBranchId], concat('BS:', COM.CUSTOMER_MNEMONIC, ':', cast(isnull(A.[CUSTOMER], aa.[CUSTOMER]) AS nvarchar(50))) 
                AS [SourceCustomerId]/*, concat('BS:' , CO_CHK.COMPANY_MNE  , ':' , cast(A.[ACCOUNT_OFFICER] as nvarchar(50))) as [SourceEmployeeId]*/ , concat('BS:', com.CUSTOMER_MNEMONIC, ':', l.[@id]) AS [SourceLimitId]/*,A.[CATEGORY] as [sourceGLId]           */ , 
                aa.[LINKED_APPL_ID] AS [AccountNum], - 1 * Rb.Debitbal AS Balance, - 1 * rb.ForeignDebitBal AS [ForeignCurrencyBal], 'Loan' AS [Category], A.[CURRENCY] AS [Currency], - 1 * rb.InterestAccrued AS [InterestAccrued], rb.InterestRate AS InterestRate, rb.FixOrVAr, 
                rb.Rate_tier_type AS RateType/*,rb.InterestRateIndex*/ , rb.InterestRateVariance, p.[@ID] AS [ProductCode], P.DESCRIPTION AS [ProductDesc], aa.PRODUCT_GROUP AS [ProductType], aa.PRODUCT_GROUP AS [T24ProductGroup], aa.START_DATE AS [StartDate], 
                isnull(aa.ORIG_CONTRACT_DATE, aa.START_DATE) OriginalStartDate, CASE WHEN a.INACTIV_MARKER = 'Y' THEN 'InActive' ELSE AA.[ARR_STATUS] END AS [StatusCode], a.[ACCOUNT_TITLE_1] AS [StatementDesc], isnull(aacd.RENEWAL_DATE, 
                aacd.MATURITY_DATE) AS MaturityDate, cast(aacd.MATURITY_DATE AS date) AS AmortMatureDate, cast(aata.[AMOUNT] AS decimal(28, 4)) AS OriginalLoanAmount, cast(aata.[AMOUNT] AS decimal(28, 4)) 
                AS Authorized/*,try_convert(int,SUBSTRING( Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM))-1 )) as Term*/ , CASE WHEN RIGHT(rtrim(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)), 1) = 'M' THEN try_convert(int, 
                SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)) WHEN RIGHT(rtrim(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)), 1) = 'D' THEN try_convert(int, round(try_convert(int, 
                SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)) * (1 / (365.25 / 12)), 0)) WHEN RIGHT(rtrim(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)), 1) = 'Y' THEN try_convert(int, round(try_convert(int, 
                SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)) * 12, 0)) ELSE NULL END AS TermInMonths, CASE WHEN RIGHT(rtrim(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)), 1) = 'M' THEN try_convert(int, 
                round(try_convert(int, SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)) * 30.44, 0)) WHEN RIGHT(rtrim(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)), 1) = 'D' THEN try_convert(int, 
                SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)) WHEN RIGHT(rtrim(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)), 1) = 'Y' THEN try_convert(int, round(try_convert(int, 
                SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)) * 365.25, 0)) ELSE NULL END AS TermInDays, aacd.START_DATE AS DisburseDate, 
                CASE WHEN aacd.ARR_AGE_STATUS = 'DEL' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS IsDelinquent/*,del.DelinquentAmount*/ , del.LastDelinquentDate/* end as PAR30*/ , 
                aacd1.CLOSURE_TYPE AS ReasonClosed/*,cast(left('20' + cast(aacd1.DATE_TIME as nvarchar(20)), 8) as date) as ClosedDate */ , - 1 * rb.DebitBal AS [AvailableFunds], LEFT(arrschedule.Start_date, 8) AS FirstPmtDate, CASE WHEN arrschedule.Actual_Amt IS NULL 
                THEN arrschedule.Calc_Amount ELSE arrschedule.Actual_Amt END AS ScheduledPmtAmt, CASE WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e1M%' AND payment_freq NOT LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Monthly' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e1M%' AND 
                payment_freq LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Twice a month' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e2M%' AND payment_freq NOT LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Every 2 month' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e2M%' AND 
                payment_freq LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Twice every 2 month' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e1W%' OR
                payment_freq LIKE '%e7D%' THEN 'Weekly' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e2W%' OR
                payment_freq LIKE '%e14D%' THEN 'Bi-Weekly' ELSE 'N/A' END AS PmtFreq, CASE WHEN intfreq LIKE '%e1M%' AND intfreq NOT LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Monthly' WHEN intFreq LIKE '%e1M%' AND 
                intfreq LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Twice a month' WHEN intFreq LIKE '%e2M%' AND intfreq NOT LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Every 2 month' WHEN intFreq LIKE '%e2M%' AND intfreq LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 'Twice every 2 month' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e1W%' OR
                payment_freq LIKE '%e7D%' THEN 'Weekly' WHEN payment_freq LIKE '%e2W%' OR
                payment_freq LIKE '%e14D%' THEN 'Bi-Weekly' ELSE 'N/A' END AS InterestPaidFreq, arrschedule.payment_type AS PmtCalcMethod, 'BSAA_Lending' AS SystemSource, /* AMK Specific*/ try_convert(date, aacd.PAYMENT_START_DATE) AS PaymentStartDt, 
                try_convert(date, aacd.RENEWAL_DATE) AS RollOverDt, CASE WHEN aacd.RENEWAL_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS RollOverStatus, try_convert(date, se.TransactionDate) AS LastPaymentDate, try_convert(money, allcod.[TOTAL_DUE]) 
                AS OverDueAmt, pad.[AUTO_CLASS] AS OverDueStatus, /* alli.[LOAN_PURPOSE] as PurposeCode,*/ try_convert(varchar(50), insight.dbo.fn_SplitOneValue(alli.loan_Purpose, 0xFDF8, 1)) AS PurposeCode, ahlp.[DESCRIPTION] AS PurposeDesc, 
                /*try_convert(int,case when charindex (CONVERT(nchar(1),0xFDF8), alli.[LOAN_PURPOSE] ) > 0 then left ( alli.[LOAN_PURPOSE], charindex (CONVERT(nchar(1),0xFDF8),alli.[LOAN_PURPOSE]) - 1) else try_convert(int,alli.[LOAN_PURPOSE])  end) as PurposeCode,*/ try_convert(varchar(50),
                 insight.dbo.fn_SplitOneValue(alli.loan_Purpose, 0xFDF8, 2)) AS PurposeCode2, ahlp3.[DESCRIPTION] AS PurposeDesc2, try_convert(varchar(50), insight.dbo.fn_SplitOneValue(alli.loan_Purpose, 0xFDF8, 3)) AS PurposeCode3, ahlp4.[DESCRIPTION] AS PurposeDesc3, 
                alli.[LOAN_CYCLE] AS LoanCycle, CASE WHEN aaalr.[WOF_STATUS] = 'WOF' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS WOFStatus, /*case when a.ALT_ACCT_TYPE = 'WOF' then then Copy the Balance in WriteOffAmt*/ alli.WRITE_OFF_AMT AS WOFAmt, 
                aaalr.[AMK_RESCHED_LN] AS Rescheduled, CASE WHEN aaalr.[AMK_RESCHED_LN] = 'Yes' THEN a.[WORKING_BALANCE] ELSE NULL END AS RescheduleAmt, aaalr.[AMK_LONG_TERM] AS LongTerm, 
                /*isnull(try_convert(int,SUBSTRING( Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, len(isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM))-1 )),alli.TENURE) as Term,*/ isnull(try_convert(int, SUBSTRING(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM), 1, 
                len(isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, aata.TERM)) - 1)), LEFT(SUBSTRING(alli.TENURE, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', alli.TENURE), 8000), PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', SUBSTRING(alli.TENURE, PATINDEX('%[0-9.-]%', alli.TENURE), 8000) + 'X') - 1)) AS Term, RIGHT(try_convert(varchar, 
                rtrim(isnull(Isnull(aacp.CHANGE_PERIOD, try_convert(nvarchar, aata.TERM)), alli.TENURE))), 1) AS TermUnit, concat('BS:', CO_CHK.COMPANY_MNE, ':', cast(alli.CREDIT_OFFICER AS nvarchar(50))) AS SourceEmployeeId, CurrUSD.MidRevalRate AS USDMidRevalRate, 
                CurrTHB.MidRevalRate AS THBMidRevalRate, isnull(- 1 * Rb.Debitbal, 0) / CurrUSD.MidRevalRate AS BalanceUSDEquiv, isnull(- 1 * Rb.Debitbal, 0) / CurrTHB.MidRevalRate AS BalanceTHBEquiv, pad.AUTO_CLASS AS Auto_Class, try_convert(money, 
                pad.POST_PROV_AMT) AS Post_Prov_Amt, allcod.ARREAR_DAYS AS DelinquentDays, CASE WHEN allcod.ARREAR_DAYS BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS PAR30, try_convert(money, allcod.TOTAL_DUE) AS DelinquentAmount, 
                lsa.LoanSettlementAccount, a.CLOSURE_DATE AS ClosedDate, alli.[MAIN_BUSINESS] AS PurposeSectorCode, ahlp2.DESCRIPTION AS PurposeSectorDesc, col.COLLATERAL_CODE AS PriCollCode, colc.DESCRIPTION AS PriCollDesc, try_convert(money, 
                allcod.PRIN_DUE) + try_convert(money, allcod.LN_BALANCE) AS Overdue_PR
   FROM    [InsightSource].[BS].[AA_ARRANGEMENT] aa LEFT JOIN
                [InsightSource].[BS].[COMPANY] COM ON COM.MNEMONIC = AA.BRANCH_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
                [InsightSource].[BS].[COMPANY_CHECK_Company_Mne] CO_CHK ON CO_CHK.[@ID] = 'MASTER' AND CO_CHK.[Sequence] = 1 LEFT JOIN
                [InsightSource].[BS].[ACCOUNT] a ON a.LEAD_CO_MNE = COM.FINANCIAL_MNE AND A.[@ID] = aa.LINKED_APPL_ID LEFT JOIN
                [InsightSource].BS.LIMIT l ON a.CUSTOMER + '.' + RIGHT('0000' + a.LIMIT_REF, 10) = l.[@ID] AND l.LEAD_CO_MNE = COM.CUSTOMER_MNEMONIC LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT del1.[@id], DEL1.ARRANGEMENT_ID, Del1.LEAD_CO_MNE, del1.LastDelinquentDate, SUM(cast(bd.OS_TOTAL_AMOUNT AS decimal(28, 4))) AS DelinquentAmount
                    FROM    (SELECT aad.[@id], AAD.LEAD_CO_MNE, AAD.ARRANGEMENT_ID, min(billpay.Bill_Pay_date) AS LastDelinquentDate, max(billpay.Bill_Pay_date) AS MaxDelinquentDate
                                  FROM    (SELECT [@id], [LEAD_CO_MNE], ARR_AGE_STATUS, [@ID] AS ARRANGEMENT_ID, BILL_PAY_DATE
                                                FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS
                                                WHERE  ARR_AGE_STATUS IN ('NAB', 'DEL')) aad JOIN
                                                    (SELECT *
                                                    FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS_Bill_Pay_date
                                                    WHERE Aging_Status = 'DEL' OR
                                                                 bill_status = 'Aging') billpay ON aad.[@id] = billpay.[@id] AND aad.[LEAD_CO_MNE] = billpay.[LEAD_CO_MNE]
                                  GROUP BY aad.[@id], AAD.ARRANGEMENT_ID, aad.[LEAD_CO_MNE]) Del1 JOIN
                                 [InsightSource].BS.AA_BILL_DETAILS bd ON del1.LEAD_CO_MNE = bd.LEAD_CO_MNE AND bd.[ARRANGEMENT_ID] = DEL1.ARRANGEMENT_ID
                    /*and del1.MaxDelinquentDate = bd.actual_pay_date*/ GROUP BY del1.[@id], DEL1.ARRANGEMENT_ID, del1.[LEAD_CO_MNE], del1.LastDelinquentDate) del ON AA.LEAD_CO_MNE = DEL.LEAD_CO_MNE AND AA.[@ID] = DEL.ARRANGEMENT_ID LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT LEAD_CO_MNE, ID_COMP_1, replace(max(CHANGE_PERIOD), 'R_BIRTH + ', '') AS CHANGE_PERIOD
                    FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARR_CHANGE_PRODUCT arr1
                    WHERE ID_COMP_3 =
                                     (SELECT MAX(ID_COMP_3)
                                     FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARR_CHANGE_PRODUCT arr2
                                     WHERE arr1.ID_COMP_1 = arr2.ID_COMP_1)
                    GROUP BY ID_COMP_1, LEAD_CO_MNE) aacp ON COM.FINANCIAL_MNE = aacp.LEAD_CO_MNE AND AA.[@ID] = aacp.ID_Comp_1 LEFT JOIN
                CTE_aacd1 aacd1 ON aacd1.LEAD_CO_MNE = COM.CUSTOMER_MNEMONIC AND aacd1.ACCOUNT_NO = A.[@ID] LEFT JOIN
                    (SELECT *
                    FROM    (SELECT [@ID], [LEAD_CO_MNE], PRODUCT, PRODUCT_STATUS, Rank() OVER (partition BY [@id]
                                  ORDER BY [PROD_EFF_DATE]) AS rank_
                    FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARRANGEMENT_PRODUCT
                    WHERE [PRODUCT_STATUS] = 'CURRENT') aap1
   WHERE aap1.rank_ = 1) aap ON aa.[@ID] = aap.[@ID] AND AAP.[LEAD_CO_MNE] = COM.[FINANCIAL_MNE] LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].BS.AA_PRODUCT p ON CASE WHEN COM.SPCL_FIN_FILE IS NULL THEN COM.DEFAULT_FINAN_MNE ELSE COM.SPCL_FIN_MNE END = P.BRANCH_CO_MNE AND AAP. PRODUCT = P.[@ID] LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].BS.AA_ACCOUNT_DETAILS aacd ON aacd.[LEAD_CO_MNE] = COM.FINANCIAL_MNE AND aacd.[@ID] = aa.[@ID] LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ps.[@id], ps.LEAD_CO_MNE, ps.ID_Comp_1, ps.Base_date, sf.Calc_Amount, sf.Actual_amt, sf.payment_freq, sf.payment_type, ps.Start_date, SFI.DUE_FREQ AS intFreq, CASE WHEN sf.payment_freq LIKE '%e1M%' AND 
                 sf.payment_freq NOT LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 1 WHEN sf.payment_freq LIKE '%e1M%' AND sf.payment_freq LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 2 WHEN sf.payment_freq LIKE '%e2M%' AND 
                 sf.payment_freq LIKE '%o%,%D%' THEN 1 WHEN sf.payment_freq LIKE '%e1W%' THEN 4 WHEN sf.payment_freq LIKE '%e2W%' THEN 2 END AS NumPmtInOneMonth
    FROM    [InsightSource].bs.AA_ARR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULE ps JOIN
                 [InsightSource].bs.AA_ARR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_payment_freq sf ON ps.[@id] = sf.[@id] AND ps.[LEAD_CO_MNE] = sf.[LEAD_CO_MNE] AND sequence = 1 LEFT JOIN
                 [InsightSource].bs.AA_ARR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULE_payment_freq_property sfi ON ps.[@id] = sfi.[@id] AND ps.[lead_co_mne] = sfi.[lead_co_mne] AND sfi.property = 'INTEREST' AND sfi.MVsequence = 1 AND sfi.sequence = 1
    WHERE ps.id_comp_3 =
                     (SELECT MAX(id_comp_3)
                     FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARR_PAYMENT_SCHEDULE arr2
                     WHERE ps.ID_COMP_1 = arr2.ID_COMP_1) AND sf.Calc_Amount IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ps.LEAD_CO_MNE, ps.[@id], ps.ID_Comp_1, ps.Base_date, sf.Calc_Amount, sf.Actual_amt, sf.payment_freq, sf.payment_type, ps.Start_date, SFI.DUE_FREQ, [bill_produced]) arrSchedule ON aa.LEAD_CO_MNE = arrSchedule.LEAD_CO_MNE AND 
AA.[@ID] = arrSchedule.ID_Comp_1 LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT LEAD_CO_MNE, max(REVOLVING) AS REVOLVING, max(TERM) AS TERM, max(AMOUNT) AS amount, ID_COMP_1
    FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARR_TERM_AMOUNT arr1
    WHERE ID_COMP_3 =
                     (SELECT MAX(ID_COMP_3)
                     FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARR_TERM_AMOUNT arr2
                     WHERE arr1.ID_COMP_1 = arr2.ID_COMP_1)
    GROUP BY ID_COMP_1, LEAD_CO_MNE) aata ON COM.FINANCIAL_MNE = aata.LEAD_CO_MNE AND AA.[@ID] = aata.ID_Comp_1 LEFT JOIN
[v_sourceAccountBSAA_RatesandBalances] rb ON rb.[Linked_appl_id] = aa.LINKED_APPL_ID AND rb.Lead_co_mne = aa.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT max(cast(LEFT('20' + t .DATE_TIME, 8) AS date)) AS [TransactionDate], cast(s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS varchar(150)) AS AccountNum
    FROM    [InsightSource].[BS].[STMT_ENTRY] s LEFT JOIN
                 [InsightSource].[BS].[COMPANY] COM ON COM.MNEMONIC = S.BRANCH_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
                 [InsightSource].BS.[TRANSACTION] t ON t .[@ID] = cast(s.TRANSACTION_CODE AS nvarchar(25)) AND T .LEAD_CO_MNE = COM.FINAN_FINAN_MNE
    WHERE cast(LEFT(s.TRANSACTION_CODE, 3) AS varchar(25)) = '852'
    GROUP BY s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) se ON se.AccountNum = cast(aa.[LINKED_APPL_ID] AS VARCHAR) /*          aa.LEAD_CO_MNE = alacd.[LEAD_CO_MNE]*/ LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].BS.AMK_L_LN_COLL_OD_DETS allcod ON aa.LINKED_APPL_ID = allcod.[@ID] AND aa.LEAD_CO_MNE = allcod.[LEAD_CO_MNE] LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[PV_ASSET_DETAIL] pad ON aa.LINKED_APPL_ID = pad.[@id] AND aa.LEAD_CO_MNE = pad.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM    (SELECT [ID_COMP_1] AS [@ID], [LEAD_CO_MNE], [ACCOUNT_REFERENCE], [@ID] AS AA_ID, Rank() OVER (partition BY [ID_COMP_1]
                  ORDER BY ID_COMP_3 DESC) AS rank_
    FROM    [InsightSource].BS.AA_ARR_ACCOUNT) aaa
WHERE aaa.rank_ = 1) aaa ON aa.[@ID] = aaa.[@ID] AND aa.LEAD_CO_MNE = aaa.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[AMK_L_LOAN_INFO] alli ON aaa.ACCOUNT_REFERENCE = alli.[@ID] AND aaa.LEAD_CO_MNE = alli.[LEAD_CO_MNE] LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[AMK_H_LOAN_PURPOSE] ahlp ON try_convert(int, insight.dbo.fn_SplitOneValue(alli.loan_Purpose, 0xFDF8, 1)) = ahlp.[@ID] AND alli.LEAD_CO_MNE = ahlp.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[AMK_H_LOAN_PURPOSE] ahlp2 ON alli.[MAIN_BUSINESS] = ahlp2.[@ID] AND alli.LEAD_CO_MNE = ahlp2.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[AMK_H_LOAN_PURPOSE] ahlp3 ON try_convert(int, insight.dbo.fn_SplitOneValue(alli.loan_Purpose, 0xFDF8, 2)) = ahlp3.[@ID] AND alli.LEAD_CO_MNE = ahlp3.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[AMK_H_LOAN_PURPOSE] ahlp4 ON try_convert(int, insight.dbo.fn_SplitOneValue(alli.loan_Purpose, 0xFDF8, 3)) = ahlp4.[@ID] AND alli.LEAD_CO_MNE = ahlp4.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[AA_ARR_ACCOUNT_LocalRef] aaalr ON aaa.AA_Id = aaalr.[@ID] AND aaa.LEAD_CO_MNE = aaalr.[LEAD_CO_MNE] LEFT JOIN
Curr CurrUSD ON CurrUSD.CurrencyCodeFrom = 'USD' LEFT JOIN
Curr CurrTHB ON CurrTHB.CurrencyCodeFrom = 'THB' LEFT JOIN
LoanSettlementAccount lsa ON aa.[@ID] = lsa.[@ID] AND lsa.RowNum = 1 LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[COLLATERAL] col ON aa.[CUSTOMER] = substring(col.[@id], 2, charindex('.', col.[@id], 1) - 1) AND aa.LEAD_CO_MNE = col.LEAD_CO_MNE LEFT JOIN
[InsightSource].[BS].[COLLATERAL_CODE] colc ON col.COLLATERAL_CODE = colc.[@ID] AND col.LEAD_CO_MNE = colc.LEAD_CO_MNE CROSS JOIN
[InsightStaging].[dbo].[v_sourceDate] AS Date
WHERE aa.PRODUCT_LINE = 'LENDING' AND aa.[LINKED_APPL_ID] IS NOT NULL
```

Full table structure

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
BusinessDate    date    no  3   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LeadCompany nvarchar    no  100                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SourceSystem    varchar no  2                   no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SourceAccountId nvarchar    no  208                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SourceBranchId  nvarchar    no  208                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SourceCustomerId    nvarchar    no  208                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SourceLimitId   nvarchar    no  208                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AccountNum  nvarchar    no  -1                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Balance money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ForeignCurrencyBal  money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
Category    varchar no  4                   no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Currency    nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
InterestAccrued money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
InterestRate    decimal no  9   19      14      yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
FixOrVAr    varchar no  8                   yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
RateType    nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
InterestRateVariance    float   no  8   53      NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ProductCode nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ProductDesc nvarchar    no  -1                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ProductType nvarchar    no  300                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
T24ProductGroup nvarchar    no  300                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
StartDate   date    no  3   10      0       no  (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
OriginalStartDate   datetime2   no  8   27      7       no  (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
StatusCode  nvarchar    no  100                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
StatementDesc   nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
MaturityDate    datetime2   no  8   27      7       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
AmortMatureDate date    no  3   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
OriginalLoanAmount  decimal no  13  28      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
Authorized  decimal no  13  28      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TermInMonths    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TermInDays  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
DisburseDate    datetime2   no  8   27      7       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
IsDelinquent    varchar no  3                   no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
LastDelinquentDate  datetime2   no  8   27      7       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ReasonClosed    nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AvailableFunds  money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
FirstPmtDate    nvarchar    no  -1                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ScheduledPmtAmt decimal no  13  28      14      yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
PmtFreq varchar no  19                  no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
InterestPaidFreq    varchar no  19                  no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PmtCalcMethod   nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SystemSource    varchar no  12                  no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PaymentStartDt  date    no  3   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
RollOverDt  date    no  3   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
RollOverStatus  varchar no  1                   no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
LastPaymentDate date    no  3   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
OverDueAmt  money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
OverDueStatus   nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PurposeCode varchar no  50                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PurposeDesc nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PurposeCode2    varchar no  50                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PurposeDesc2    nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PurposeCode3    varchar no  50                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PurposeDesc3    nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
LoanCycle   int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
WOFStatus   varchar no  1                   no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WOFAmt  decimal no  9   19      6       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
Rescheduled nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
RescheduleAmt   decimal no  13  28      14      yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LongTerm    nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Term    int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TermUnit    varchar no  1                   yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SourceEmployeeId    nvarchar    no  208                 no  (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
USDMidRevalRate nvarchar    no  -1                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
THBMidRevalRate nvarchar    no  -1                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
BalanceUSDEquiv money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
BalanceTHBEquiv money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
Auto_Class  nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Post_Prov_Amt   money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
DelinquentDays  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
PAR30   varchar no  3                   no  no  no  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
DelinquentAmount    money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LoanSettlementAccount   nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ClosedDate  datetime2   no  8   27      7       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
PurposeSectorCode   int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
PurposeSectorDesc   nvarchar    no  300                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PriCollCode nvarchar    no  100                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
PriCollDesc nvarchar    no  -1                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Overdue_PR  money   no  8   19      4       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
```

Comment: I'd almost put money on it coming from one of the calls to `dbo.fn_SplitOneValue`

Comment: Thank you all so much, I can figure out , and solve the problems from your tips.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Run the smallest part of code the code possible

For any large select statement like this, with lots of sub-queries, I would find the inner-most sub-query and run that by itself.

### 2. If that doesn't fail, add in the next level

Move one step "out" from that sub-query, to the next part of the query that references it.  Run that whole section.

Repeat this step as needed until you encounter the error.

**Be methodical**.  Resist the urge to jump around to different parts of the query "randomly" or because you have a hunch.  For a view definition this large, your safest and most reliable bet is to move in a clear pattern through the whole query.

### 3. Once you've found the error, remove things until it goes away

If you have a lot of string concatenation or expressions in your SELECT statement, remove them one by one until the error goes away.  This will help determine which expression is causing the problem.

Another approach would be to remove joins (and all references to the columns in the joined table) one at a time until the error goes away.

---

This should get you to a point where you know which specific column(s) and table(s) are causing you problems, and what expressions they were involved in.  Now you can look into that data and track down what's there that shouldn't be - or what's missing.